# Where in form1 and how can I start downloading again when the timer count down reached 00:00:00?

Tags: c#, winforms

The timer class

I'm checking when the TimeSpan ts variable if he gets to 0 then start counting 300 seconds down again.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class TimeCounter : Label
    {
        public bool CountUp { get; set; }
        public Timer _timer;
        public TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

        public TimeCounter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StartCountDownTimer();
        }

        public void StartCountDownTimer()
        {
            _timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 1000,
                Enabled = false
            };
            _timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if(ts == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
                {
                    ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
                }

                if (CountUp)
                {
                    ts = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    ts = ts.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                }

                this.Text = ts.ToString();
            };
        }

        private void TimeCounter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Then in Form1 I have a button click event where I start the timer and start downloading.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timeCounter1._timer.Enabled = true;
            DownloadImages();
        }

        public async void DownloadImages()
        {
            CreateDownloadFolders();

            urls = new List<string>();

            lblStatus.Text = "Downloading...";

            rad.GetRadarImages();
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            foreach (string link in rad.links)
            {
                urls.Add(link);
            }

            await sat.DownloadSatelliteAsync();
            foreach (string link in sat.SatelliteUrls())
            {
                urls.Add(link);
            }

            urlsCounter = urls.Count;

            await DownloadAsync();
        }
```

And when the download is finished

```
private async Task DownloadAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error == null)
                    {
                        urlsCounter--;

                        if (urlsCounter == 0)
                        {
                            GetImagesFiles();

                            timer1.Enabled = true;
                            timer2.Enabled = true;

                            lblStatus.Text = "Completed.";
                        }
                    }
                };
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => tracker.SetProgress(e.BytesReceived, e.TotalBytesToReceive);
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => lblAmount.Text = tracker.SizeSuffix(e.BytesReceived) + "/" + tracker.SizeSuffix(e.TotalBytesToReceive);
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => lblSpeed.Text = tracker.GetBytesPerSecondString();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => myLong = Convert.ToInt64(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]);
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                    label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
                };

                for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
                {
                    tracker.NewFile();

                    if (urls[i].Contains("Radar"))
                    {
                        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), radarFolderImagesDownload + "\\image" + radCounter + ".gif");

                        radCounter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), satelliteFolderImagesDownload + "\\image" + satCounter + ".gif");

                        satCounter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I want that when the counter TimeSpan ts variable in the TimeCounter class is reaching 00:00:00 start downloading again in form1 and so on.  I'm not going to stop the timer I want that each 5 minutes start a new download count 5 minutes down and download nonstop.

I'm not sure where and how to call the DownloadImages() method in Form1 each time the timer has reached 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom event to your TimeCounter control, then raise it when the timer hits zero:

```
public partial class TimeCounter : Label
{

    public delegate void dlgTimerTrigger(TimeCounter source);
    public event dlgTimerTrigger TimerTrigger;

    // ... other code not shown ...

            if (ts == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
            {
                ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
                if (TimerTrigger != null)
                {
                    TimerTrigger(this);
                }
            }

    // ... other code not shown ...

}
```

Now subscribe to that event in the Load() event of your form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeCounter1.TimerTrigger += TimeCounter1_TimerTrigger;
}

private void TimeCounter1_TimerTrigger(TimeCounter source)
{
    DownloadImages();
}
```